# Achieving Data Synchronization in Android App with Kotlin - Best Approach and Option?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-syncadapter, data-synchronization, backup-strategies

I am currently developing an Android application using Kotlin and need to implement data synchronization between my app and a server. I want to achieve the following functionalities:

**Backup Data**: Transfer data from my app to the server for backup purposes when the device is connected to the internet.

**Offline Access**: Ensure that users can access data from the server even when the device is offline.

**Manual Sync**: Allow users to trigger the synchronization process manually.

**Scheduled Sync**: Implement a scheduled synchronization, for example, syncing data at a specific time of the day.

I'm aware of the "**Sync Adapter**" concept in Android. **But it is most complex for me as I am beginner and I'm not sure if it's the most up-to-date and best solution for my requirements**. I need guidance on the **best approach and possibly recommendations for libraries or frameworks** that can help me achieve these functionalities efficiently.

I'm open to exploring other options if they offer a **more modern and efficient solution.**

Please Guide me....